# Accessing same hash title in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

So I have this array with a hash inside. I want to access the points key in all parts of the array. Is there anyway to do this?

```
@students = []
loop do
  puts "What is the student's name?"  
  @name = gets.chomp 
  puts "What is the students GPA?"
  @gpa = gets.chomp.to_f 

  def add_students 
    @students << {:name => @name, :gpa => @gpa, :points => @gpa * 10} 
  end 

  add_students
  puts @students 


  loop do
     puts "Would you like to add more students?"
     answer = gets.chomp
     if answer == "yes"
        break 
     elsif answer == "no"
        `say "goodbye"`
            break 
            break 
     else 
        puts "I'm sorry this is not a correct command!"
    end
 end 
end
```

Comment: Lots of craziness in your code. Why are you using instance variables (with the @s) when you have no class defined? Why are you defining a parameterless add_students function inside your loop only to then call it? Also, you can't break out of two loops with two breaks in a row, because the first break takes you out of that loop so the second one is never reached!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate an array of all the points values with...

```
points_array = @students.map{|s| s[:points] }
```